# Where is the gambler?

Tags: diablo-iii

Diablo 2 had a gambler where you could purchase items before knowing what magical properties they'll have.

I'm about halfway through Diablo 3 and have yet to stumble upon a gambler. Has anyone found him? If so, where is he?

Comment: And for the record, I don't have a gambling addiction, I swear :p

Comment: I have heard rumors that gambling vendors were removed because of the real-money linkage. If you can buy gold with real money, and use it to gamble for items you can sell for real money, some people feared that governments would restrict (or tax) the game as a gambling device.

Comment: @Wikwocket Oh wow, that's really interesting.

Comment: @Wikwocket: We'd better keep it a secret that people could possibly buy crafting materials in the auction house and use those materials to roll for random items you could possibly sell for real money.

Comment: @Jimmy It's all about perception... ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls you can find the Gamble merchant, [Kadala](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Kadala), in Adventuring mode. To gamble, you spend [Blood Shards](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Shard) that are earned through completing Bounties and within Nephalim Rifts (The Rift Boss seems to drop large chunks).

Comment: I know this is answering a super old question, but I saw it when I was googling gambling in D3. Since I imagine a lot of people may be searching for D3 and gambling I figure it is worth having an up to date answer.

Comment: I have bought 2 items from the gambler, and they were both useless. Is there something else worth using them on?

Comment: You mean blood shards? I'm not aware of any other use besides gambling

Answer (score 11):

There is no gambler.  You can get something similar - gear with random stats by paying gold - by using the Blacksmith Artisan, but that's the closest there is in Diablo 3.

Comment: There is really no mechanical  difference between the two at all, just a different in-game justification for the mechanic.

Answer (score 2):

Gambling has effectively been replaced with crafting in Diablo III. Instead of buying items with random enchantments, you create them at the Blacksmith. Spending money to upgrade the blacksmith allows you to create higher-level items.